# Does CSS have a way of creating subselectors for more compact code?

Tags: css

Normal programming languages have stuff like

```
int x, y, z;
```

so that you don't have to write out

```
int x;
int y; 
int z;
```

In CSS I often find myself having to write stuff like

```
.some-class h1, .some-class h3, .some-class p { margin-bottom: 1.2em; }
```

when it seems like there should be some compact equivalent like

```
.some-class (h1, h3, p) { margin-bottom: 1.2em; }
```

Is there such a thing?

Comment: You will need a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(stylesheet_language)#Nesting) to do something like that.

Comment: Or you can do it this way: .some-class h1, h3, p { margin-bottom: 1.2em; }

Comment: @ZiggyVerstrepen That works?

Comment: No, that selector finds h1's that are a decedent of .some-class, and also all of the h3 and p tags.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant that to be how you can achieve it with a preprocessor but I see that I forgot some brackets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a CSS preprocessor, which use indentation to show decedents. Here's how that would look in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/):

```
.some-class {
    h1, h3, p {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [CSS Selectors level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches) defines a pseudo class called `:matches`

You use it like this:

```
.some-class :matches(h1, h3, p) { margin-bottom: 1.2em; }
```

However, browser support is pretty spotty, see this CSS Tricks article for more information: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches